# Create SPA in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application

I have a navigation bar (and maybe a footer), which should be visible on every nested page. So basically just the content changes. In Vue.js I would just use `<router-view>` as placeholder for the dynamic content and `<router-link>` to switch this content.

Now in Nuxt.js I have the following dir structure.

```
pages/
--| calendar/
-----| index.vue
--| people/
-----| index.vue
--| index.vue
```

And my navigation bar consists of two `<nuxt-link>` e.g. `<nuxt-link :to="/calendar"> (some content) </nuxt-link>`. So if I click on this link, the navigation bar disappears and only the content in `/pages/calendar/index.vue` is displayed.
Sorry, I am new to nuxt, but I thought it would be possible to create a SPA like in Vue.js. I even  changed the mode from universal to spa and also used the Vue.js approache like explained above, without success.

Comment: you need to navigate to `layouts` and there is an `<nuxt />` tag. This is your "router-view". You need to put things like navigation bar and footers, maybe also sidebars inside of layout

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the main layout by adding a layouts/default.vue file. It will be used for all pages that don't have a layout specified. Make sure to add the  component when creating a layout to actually include the page component.

Something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>My blog navigation bar here</div>
    <Nuxt />
    <div>My footer is here</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

if you need use it in a sub-child route, you can use inside your pages/index.vue the NUXT-CHILD to get sub-child-nested-page...

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>FIXED BANNER</div>
      <nuxt-child />
    <div>FIXED LIST OF ITEMS </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks ;) this is definetly a way to go. So contrary to router-link, nuxt-link will always load a new page?

Comment: The nuxt-link will be used to navigate through your application, similar to the <router-link> component in a traditional Vue App. In fact, <nuxt-link> extends <router-link>. That means it takes the same properties and can be used in the same manner. Please take a look https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/